# Why are my link texts different colors?

Tags: css

My web page has this CSS:

```
html.light .auth .authInput .authLink {
  color: #007fff;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<a class="authLink" .... ></a>
```

What I notice that in one place the link is blue and in another place the link is purple.

Can someone tell me why it is a different color?

Comment: Its purple if you already clicked on it / visited the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the purple one stands for `visited`. To make this go away add a `:visited` pseudo selector like this:

```
html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:visited {
  color: #007fff;
}
```

This will ensure that the link is the same color even after you've visited it. And by visited I mean clicked on it.

Generally you want to cover the entire "LOVE HATE" of links:

```
html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:link {
  color: #007fff;
}

html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:visited {
  color: #007fff;
}

html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:hover {
  // Some color
}

html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:active {
  // Some color
}
```

"LOVE HATE" basically means that you should define `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active` in the correct order. It's just a helper for reminding which order to specify them in. (LVHA)

Comment: But what about the not yet visited state?

Comment: @SamanthaJ then you need two selectors, one to handle the normal state and one for the visited.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer so that it will appear blue for all states

Answer (score 0):

```
html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:link {
   color: #007fff;
}
html.light .auth .authInput .authLink:visited {
   color: #007fff;
}
```

The first CSS says unvisited links should be a certain color.

The second CSS says visited links should be a certain color (in this case, the same color as the unvisited links).

If you want :hover (when a mouse hovers a link) or :active (when a mouse clicks on a link) states, and more...

...click here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

I would provide the solution for all of the states (as the comment above me did), but it's better to know *why* certain things behave in certain ways, rather than just copying and pasting an answer because you'll inevitably come across the problem again in the future.

For example, the selectors need to be in a certain order, and by copying and pasting the code you may try to manipulate it yourself or recycle it for something else, and then you'll come across some malfunctioning code because you put the hover state before the link state, or something similar to that, and you'll be scratching your head wondering what's going on, whereas if you understood it to start off with you'd never have that problem. =)